# One category classification at Keras

Tags: keras

I need to create CNN on Keras only to recognize one specific type of an image, credit card in my case. So seems I only need one ouput sigmoid neuron. But the question is how to train such network, because I have only one target category. Or I should add random images with cats and dogs to say to NN it's not credit card. I'm not even sure it is binary classification. I don't have any code yet, but for first I'll try VGG-16 from Keras docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you're using VGG-16 with transfer learning, one immediate approach could be to add your credit card images to the ImageNet data. You could label all other images simply `not credit card`, and fine-tune either a softmax over two output neurons (`credit card` vs `not credit card`) or a sigmoid activation that represents confidence that an image is a credit card.

This would fine-tune over a diverse set of alternative images that should ultimately result in a more robust and accurate classifier.

But if you're considering deploying this for a real-world use case you'll need to think carefully about the mapping between the ImageNet image format (resolution etc.) and preprocessing and the format in the use case. Testing results on ImageNet will likely outperform results on the real-world data. The ideal would be to collect non credit card examples from the use case and fine-tune using these.

Comment: Thank you for reply. If I get it right, if I use one output with sigmoid activation I could compare the ouput value with some border value, 0.7 for example. And if output > 0.7 it's likely credit card, and if <= it is not?

Comment: Exactly. And you could choose that threshold based on your tolerance for false negatives and false positives, for instance.

Comment: Could you please tell me some example of such model? Maybe from Keras docs or something else. I'm not sure I saw any model like this :(

Comment: Sure- simple [binary model](https://chrisalbon.com/deep_learning/keras/feedforward_neural_network_for_binary_classification/), where your loss function is binary crossentropy. Train normally, then the `predict` method gives you a sequence of predicted probabilities of being a credit card. You can then define a simple function to count the false positives and false negatives at different probability thresholds `[0, .05, .1, ..., .95]`, and choose the one most suitable for your objective. This is subjective— e.g you want to be very certain that the positive cases you identity are truly positive.